# Can I use php function strtotime() in sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, time, subtraction

```
id     time       lastTime
1      08:02
2      08:04
3      08:30
```

I am using this query with the `strtotime()` and its not working.

```
UPDATE table
SET lastTime = strtotime(time) - strtotime('08:00');
```

How it can be done?

Comment: `strtotime()` is a php function not a mysql function.

Comment: also what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
UPDATE table
SET lastTime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('08:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it and execut $query variable

```
$time = strtotime(time) - strtotime('08:00');
$query = " UPDATE table SET lastTime = '$time'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `table` SET table.`lastTime` = SUBTIME(table.`time`, '08:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can use:

```
dateadd(hour,-8,GETDATE()) -- for 8 hours down
dateadd(hour,-14*24,GETDATE()) -- for 14 days down
```